# How can I patch a rotting wood door?

Tags: wood, patch

I have a small rotting spot at the bottom of my back door and it's almost to the point where I could put my finger through it.  I don't have the cash to replace the door right now, but what would you suggest I patch it with before painting it?  I have seen interior/exterior wood filler by Elmer's and others.  Someone suggested Bondo like the kind used in auto body shops.  Any prep steps you suggest as well?

Answer (score 2):

Dig out any rotted wood that you can get to.  Soak the wood with wood hardener around the patch area to stabilize the rotted/deteriorated wood that you couldn't get to.  Fill with bondo or wood filler in 1/4" layers until slightly bulging from the patch area.  Chisel/file/sand down when the final layer is almost completely dry with a sanding block.  Prime and paint.  The patch should outlast the rest of your door!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the spot is really bad, you can cut it out with a saw, and replace with doweled and glued good wood. Since you're painting, a carefully done job of this shouldn't even be visible.